# Android Pop-up message

Tags: android, popup

I'm trying to get a pop up text box, with some disclaimer and app info at the start of my Android application's launch. Does anyone know how to implement this? Also could it read from a txt file?

Thanks

Comment: Try AlertDialog: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097513/android-simple-alert-dialog - first answer has example code.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you want a Popup that closes automatically, you should look for [Toasts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html). But if you want a dialog that the user has to close first before proceeding, you should look for a [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

For both approaches it is possible to read a text file with the text you want to display. But you could also hardcode the text or use R.String to set the text.

Comment: Your approach is very good, how to do it for 2 messages that come in handy for example toast

Answer (score 41):

You can use Dialog to create this easily

create a Dialog instance using the context

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(contex);
```

You can design your layout as you like.

You can add this layout to your dialog by
    `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popupview);//popup view is the layout you created`

then you can access its content (textviews, etc.) by using `findViewById` method

```
TextView txt = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.textbox);
```

you can add any text here. the text can be stored in the String.xml file in res\values.

```
txt.setText(getString(R.string.message));
```

then finally show the pop up menu

```
dialog.show();
```

more information
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html

Answer (score 4):

Use This And Call This In OnCreate Method In Which Activity You Want

```
public void popupMessage(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("No Internet Connection. Check Your Wifi Or enter code hereMobile Data.");
        alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_no_internet);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Connection Failed");
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Log.d("internet","Ok btn pressed");
                // add these two lines, if you wish to close the app:
                finishAffinity();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to set a pop-up text box for clicking a button lets say **bt** whose id is **button**, then code using **Toast** will somewhat look like this:

```
Button bt;
bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {            
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"The text you want to display",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sample code show custom dialog in kotlin:

```
fun showDlgFurtherDetails(context: Context,title: String?, details: String?) {

    val dialog = Dialog(context)
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    dialog.setCancelable(false)
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dlg_further_details)
    dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
    val lblService = dialog.findViewById(R.id.lblService) as TextView
    val lblDetails = dialog.findViewById(R.id.lblDetails) as TextView
    val imgCloseDlg = dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgCloseDlg) as ImageView

    lblService.text = title
    lblDetails.text = details
    lblDetails.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod()
    lblDetails.isScrollbarFadingEnabled = false
    imgCloseDlg.setOnClickListener {
        dialog.dismiss()
    }
    dialog.show()
}
```