# Android simple alert dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I need to show a little text message to the users that clicks a button on my Android app, on IOS I just had to create an AlertView that it's simple to use but with Android i'm struggling because the solution seems x10 times harder. I saw that I need to use a DialogFragment but I can't understand how to make it work, can someone explain? Also, is my solution right or there is something easier to show a simple text message to users?

Answer (score 488, accepted):

You would simply need to do this in your `onClick`:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
alertDialog.show();
```

I don't know from where you saw that you need DialogFragment for simply showing an alert.

Comment: FYI - The first example at Google's Android Dev site shows how to do this using a Fragment : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html 
I think that is possibly what leads a dev to think he needs to use a fragment for a basic AlertDialog. I searched today and thought maybe so.

Comment: Better to set properties on the builder rather than the alertDialog instance!

Answer (score 30):

No my friend its very simple, try using this:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogActivity.this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");
alertDialog.setMessage("Welcome to dear user.");
alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.welcome);

alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

alertDialog.show();
```

This [tutorial](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Dialog_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=88&aaid=111) shows how you can create custom dialog using xml and then show them as an alert dialog.

Comment: You haven't passed which button.

Answer (score 25):

You can easily make your own 'AlertView' and use it everywhere.

```
alertView("You really want this?");
```

Implement it once:

```
private void alertView( String message ) {
 AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
 dialog.setTitle( "Hello" )
       .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
       .setMessage(message)
//     .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {
//          dialoginterface.cancel();   
//          }})
      .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {   
        }               
        }).show();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but how do I get `context` ? I am using `androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog`