# Can't show a simple message in an Android App

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015

I started developing Android apps today using Visual Studio 2015 and I'd like to know why I can't show an AlertDialog, because it throws me an exception about `Android.Views.WindowManagerBadTokenException` and I don't see where I'm mistaken..

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Button)sender).Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++);
    try
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.ApplicationContext);
        builder.SetTitle("This is a title..");
        builder.SetMessage("This is a message..");
        AlertDialog ad = builder.Create();
        ad.Show();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { ((Button)sender).Text = ex.Message; }
}
```

Comment: `this.ApplicationContext` why? why don't you use `this` directly?

Comment: I thought I gotta send the `ApplicationContext` because it requests a Context in the constructor..

Comment: for some reason, alertdialog requests a context, but will only work with an activity context (nice design, android...). You need an activity here. (`this` is probably an activity, isn't it?)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you just started developing for Android, **USE ANDROID STUDIOS** unless you have a really really good reason to develop in Visual Studios.  Android Studios is the best IDE I've ever used and I highly recommend it.

But, if you would like to stick with Visual Studios, try this code:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
alertDialog.show();
```

Pulled from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097513/android-simple-alert-dialog) question.  Maybe it's because your .Create() and .Show() should be all lower case instead of camel case.

Comment: `new AlertDialog.Builder(this)` worked for me as njzk2 said.

Comment: Oh alright, awesome.  But seriously, in [Android Studios](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) it would have found that error in no time at all. I highly recommend it.