# How to show alertDialog Box using mvvm pattern

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-mvvm

I am working on a login module where I have to show alert dialog if the login is unsuccessful.
I have a authentication process in viewmodel and I have to display an error in alert dialog.How it can be done?

Comment: Does your login has an usecase using completable or observable? If you can put some code for us to understand how you're setting things up would help.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this answer to show alert dialog. All you need to change is, showing your error message in the setMessage method.

[Android simple alert dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097513/android-simple-alert-dialog)