# Android Java: AlertDialog method called from another class causes null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to call a method from another class which then calls an `AlertDialog` method, and I've tried many things but it always causes a null pointer exception. The calling class is running a web server, and I have a `RecyclerView` list on the activity class containing the method being called. here's some code from the activity class with `AlertDialog`:

```
public class ListClass extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebSvr server;
    private static final int PORT = 8080;
    private androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar;
    private ListView lv;
    private CustomAdapter customAdapter;
    public ArrayList<EditModel> editModelArrayList;
    public static String[] newList = new String[20];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_server_screen);
        toolbar = (androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        startWebServer();

        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, editModelArrayList);
        lv.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }

    public static boolean listUpdated;

    public void updateList() {
        listUpdated = false;
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    if (CustomAdapter.editModelArrayList.get(i).getEditTextValue() != "") {
                        newList[i] = CustomAdapter.editModelArrayList.get(i).getEditTextValue();
                    } else {
                        if (!showNotification) {

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    showNullFieldNotification(); // <------------- CALLING THIS 
                                }
                            });
                            showNotification = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                listUpdated = true;
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(r);
        thread.start();
    }

    boolean showNotification = false;

    public void showNullFieldNotification() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(ListClass.this)
                .setTitle("Warning, some fields are empty")
                .setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                        showNotification = false;
                    }
                }).show();
    }

    public static boolean returnListUpdated() {
        return listUpdated;
    }

...

}
```

And here's the code from my web server class:

```
public class WebSvr extends NanoHTTPD {

    public ListClass ListClass = new ListClass();

    public WebSvr(int port){
        super(port);
    }

    @Override
    public Response serve(String uri, Method method,
                          Map<String, String> header,
                          Map<String, String> parameters,
                          Map<String, String> files) {


        ListClass.updateList(); // <--------------- THE METHOD CALLED

        while (!ListClass.returnListUpdated()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        String strResponse = Arrays.toString(ListClass.returnString());

        return newFixedLengthResponse(strResponse);
    }
}
```

It always causes null pointer exception on this line:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(ListClass.this)
```

and where the method is called in `ListClass`:

```
showNullFieldNotification();
```

Error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.espressif.iot_esptouch_demo, PID: 18217
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:152)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:157)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:224)
        at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:454)
        at com.myProject.ListClass.showNullFieldNotification(ListClass.java:177)
        at com.myProject.ListClass$4.run(ListClass.java:193)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6665)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:772)
```

If I call `showNullFieldNotification()` in `ListClass` `onCreate()` or from the options menu it works no problem, but when called from the `WebSvr` class it always causes the exception.

For context on the `AlertDialog` I've tried `ListClass.this`, `getApplicationContext()`, `getBaseContext()`... I've tried to save a context in `onCreate` as `getApplicationContext()` and use that.

I've tried to use the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-in-android) question to get context but that didn't work either. Would really appreciate any help.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I had also tried to build the alert in this way:

```
public void showNullFieldNotification2() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListClass.this);
                alert.setTitle("Warning, some fields detected as being empty or having \"0\" as value");
                alert.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                        showNotification = false;
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
                dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I actually read that answer yesterday, after reading it I tried using the method which I have updated at the end of my question to see if it would add some needed initialization but it didn't help. Other than that I can’t think of a way it provides a solution to my particular problem aside from what I've already tried. Do you have a specific suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806051/accessing-sharedpreferences-through-static-methods) in answer from [Dan Bray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2452680/dan-bray). Needed to use a static context.

Since you are calling from outside of an activity, you'll need to save the context in activity class:

```
public static Context context;
```

And inside onCreate:

```
context = this;
```

To show notification:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){

                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle("Warning, some fields are empty")
                        .setNegativeButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface,int i){
                                dialogInterface.cancel();
                                showNotification=false;
                            }
                        }).show();

            }
        });
```

The methods called in the activity class must also be `public static`.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot create Alert Dialog so it null, not the context

[Android simple alert dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097513/android-simple-alert-dialog)

Comment: I've tried to use the solution from this answer to get context but that didn't work either\
I've actually already tried that, I updated the question with the method I used. And the method used which does not use .create() works fine when called from the same class so I don't believe it makes any difference.